# Convert XML string to org.w3c.dom.Document?

Tags: javascript, java, xml

I have the following XML string, I want to convert this string to org.w3c.dom.Document in order to get the value of 'CallPaySecureResult' element.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<S:Body xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <ns2:CallPaySecureResponse xmlns:ns2="https://paysecure/merchant.soap/">
      <CallPaySecureResult>&amp;lt;status&amp;gt;success&amp;lt;/status&amp;gt;&amp;lt;errorcode&amp;gt;0&amp;lt;/errorcode&amp;gt;&amp;lt;errormsg /&amp;gt;&amp;lt;guid&amp;gt;d785f819-6fc1-1c68-8edf-bbb65cba5412&amp;lt;/guid&amp;gt;&amp;lt;/paysecure&amp;gt;</CallPaySecureResult>
   </ns2:CallPaySecureResponse>
</S:Body>
```

I have tried the following code

```java
public String processIssuerResultParameters(String strXML)throws Exception
    {

            DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();  
            DocumentBuilder builder; 
            Document doc=null;
            String CallPaySecureResult ="";
            try  
            {  
                builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();  
                doc = builder.parse( new InputSource( new StringReader( strXML ) ) ); 
             logger.severe(doc.getTextContent());
            } catch (Exception e) {  
                return "1:"+e.toString()+doc.getTextContent();  
            } 
   }
```

I have tried this:

```
InputSource is= new InputSource(new StringReader(strXML));
            DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
            builder = null;
            builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
            doc = builder.parse(is);
```

and this :

```
Source source = new StreamSource(new StringReader(strXML));
            DOMResult result = new DOMResult();
            TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer().transform(source , result);
            doc = (Document) result.getNode();
```

But in all the cases variable 'doc' is null.

How can I parse the XML(string) to Document and get the value in `<CallPaySecureResult>`?

Comment: Use stack snippets if you have code that can run in the browser and 4 spaces or {} button if you have just code.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some examples + context.

You should take a look at the entire file:
https://github.com/bcdev/ceres/blob/master/ceres-metadata/src/main/java/com/bc/ceres/metadata/XPathHandler.java#L76

```
private static Document transformToDocument(Object document) {
    try {
        String docString;
        if (document instanceof ReaderResource) {
            docString = ((ReaderResource) document).getContent();
        } else if (document instanceof String) {
            docString = (String) document;
        } else if (document instanceof Element) { //used?
            DOMSource domSource = new DOMSource((Element) document);
            StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
            StreamResult result = new StreamResult(writer);
            TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
            Transformer transformer = tf.newTransformer();
            Properties properties = new Properties();
            properties.setProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD, "xml");
            properties.setProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "yes");
            transformer.setOutputProperties(properties);
            transformer.transform(domSource, result);
            docString = writer.toString();
        } else {
            return null;
        }

        InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(docString.getBytes());
        return DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().parse(is);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not able to convert string to Document. I have tried many ways to convert in to Document.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you:

```
public class Convert {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Document copyBookXml = XmlUtils.fileToDom(args[1]);
    Document sourceDocument = XmlUtils.fileToDom(args[0]);
    // params 1) XML source document 2) Copybook as XML
    String result = new XmlToMainframe().convert(sourceDocument, copyBookXml);
    FileUtils.writeFile(result, "mfresult.txt", false);
  }
}
```

Full code here (code.openhub.net):

http://code.openhub.net/file?fid=e0O83oBJw47fhoPbZm0MgKWWStk&cid=7VtqxYTpWXE&s=Convert%20XML%20string%20to%20org.w3c.dom.Document%3F&pp=0&fl=Java&ff=1&projSelected=false&filterChecked,=true&mp,=1&filterChecked=true&mp=1&ml=1&me=1&md=1#L14

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the namespace when try to get the element, below is the working code:

```
private static String input = 
     "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>"
     +"<S:Body xmlns:S=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">"
     +"<ns2:CallPaySecureResponse xmlns:ns2=\"https://paysecure/merchant.soap/\">"
     +"<CallPaySecureResult>&amp;lt;status&amp;gt;success&amp;lt;/status&amp;gt;&amp;lt;errorcode&amp;gt;0&amp;lt;/errorcode&amp;gt;&amp;lt;errormsg /&amp;gt;&amp;lt;guid&amp;gt;d785f819-6fc1-1c68-8edf-bbb65cba5412&amp;lt;/guid&amp;gt;&amp;lt;/paysecure&amp;gt;</CallPaySecureResult>"
     +"</ns2:CallPaySecureResponse>"
     +"</S:Body>";

DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
docFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);
DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

InputSource is= new InputSource(new StringReader(input));
Document doc = docBuilder.parse(is);

String docNS = "https://paysecure/merchant.soap/";

NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagNameNS(docNS, "CallPaySecureResponse");
String s = nl.getLength()> 0 ?nl.item(0).getTextContent():"ELEMENT NOT FOUND";
System.out.println(s);
```

output:

```
 &lt;status&gt;success&lt;/status&gt;&lt;errorcode&gt;0&lt;/errorcode&gt;&lt;errormsg /&gt;&lt;guid&gt;d785f819-6fc1-1c68-8edf-bbb65cba5412&lt;/guid&gt;&lt;/paysecure&gt;
```

hope this can help.